# EXCEL VBA String length over 3 lines based on length , spaces, "/", or " _" characters

Tags: excel, vba

Based on the code Zac gave me in

[String length over 3 lines based on length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49445290/string-length-over-3-lines-based-on-length)

I now need to update to it to include the possibility that the text/words may not be separated by spaces but also the characters "/" or "_". I've had a good fiddle without success. 
I added if statements to the function such as :-

```
If InStr(55, sText, "_") > 0 Then
        sGreater55 = Mid(sText, InStr(55, sText, "_"))
```

Without success :-(

```
Function SetString(ByVal sText As String) As String
    Dim sGreater55$, sGreater19$
```

' If text is greater than 55 characters, first lets capture the string after 55 characters (depending on where the SPACE character is)

```
If Len(sText) > 55 Then
    If InStr(55, sText, " ") > 0 Then
        sGreater55 = Mid(sText, InStr(55, sText, " "))
    Else
        sGreater55 = Mid(sText, InStrRev(sText, " ", 55))
    End If
End If
```

' If text is greater than 19 characters, lets build the string after 19 characters (depending on where the SPACE character is)

```
If Len(sText) > 19 Then
    If InStr(19, sText, " ") > 0 Then
        sGreater19 = Mid(sText, InStr(19, sText, " "))
    Else
        sGreater19 = Mid(sText, InStrRev(sText, " ", 19))
    End If
    sGreater19 = Left(sGreater19, Len(sGreater19) - Len(sGreater55))
End If
```

' Now lets build the complete string

```
SetString = Left(sText, Len(sText) - (Len(sGreater19) + Len(sGreater55))) & vbLf & sGreater19 & vbLf & sGreater55

End Function
```

Comment: Can you give a sample of some inputs, with expected output? Have you looked in to regex at all?

Comment: Oops , missed that from the post. examples inputs are 'blah blah blah blah blah' or 'blah_blah_blah_blah_blah_blahblah' or 'blah/blah/blahblahblah/blah' etc etc Should split the string by a space , / or _ . If over 19 characters then 2 lines if over 55 characters then 3 lines. It works fine with the space only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there might be an mixture of the *split* characters (Eg `blah_blah_blah blah_blah/blahblah`: Create a copy of your input string, replace all possible *split* characters by blank and slighly modify the function:

```
Function SetString(ByVal sText As String) As String
    Dim sGreater55$, sGreater19$
    Dim sTextCopy As String
    sTextCopy = Replace(Replace(sText, "/", " "), "_", " ")

    ' If text is greater than 55 characters, first lets capture the string after 55 characters (depending on where the SPACE character is)
    If Len(sText) > 55 Then
        If InStr(55, sText, " ") > 0 Then
            sGreater55 = Mid(sText, InStr(55, sTextCopy, " "))
        Else
            sGreater55 = Mid(sText, InStrRev(sTextCopy, " ", 55))
        End If
    End If

    ' If text is greater than 19 characters, lets build the string after 19 characters (depending on where the SPACE character is)
    If Len(sText) > 19 Then
        If InStr(19, sText, " ") > 0 Then
            sGreater19 = Mid(sText, InStr(19, sTextCopy, " "))
        Else
            sGreater19 = Mid(sText, InStrRev(sTextCopy, " ", 19))
        End If
        sGreater19 = Left(sGreater19, Len(sGreater19) - Len(sGreater55))
    End If

    ' Now lets build the complete string
    SetString = Left(sText, Len(sText) - (Len(sGreater19) + Len(sGreater55))) & vbLf & sGreater19 & vbLf & sGreater55

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly Assumptions:

- Text provided to UDF will have one of the 3 "dividers" separating text (i.e. text is divided by a space or "_" or "/"). Provided text is not separated by a combination of the "dividers" (i.e. don't have text like `blah blah blah\blah\blah`)
- If non of the 3 "dividers" exist in the provided text, empty string is returned

Based on the above assumptions, try this:

```
Function SetString(ByVal sText As String) As String
    Dim sGreater55$, sGreater19$
    Dim sChrToCheck As String: sChrToCheck = ""

    ' First lets decide which character we need to use to seperate string
    If InStr(1, sText, " ") > 0 Then
        sChrToCheck = " "
    ElseIf InStr(1, sText, "_") > 0 Then
        sChrToCheck = "_"
    ElseIf InStr(1, sText, "/") > 0 Then
        sChrToCheck = "/"
    Else
        ' Non of the expected text dividers found in the specified string to return an empty string
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' If text is greater than 55 characters, first lets capture the string after 55 characters (depending on where the SPACE character is)
    If Len(sText) > 55 Then
        If InStr(55, sText, sChrToCheck) > 0 Then
            sGreater55 = Mid(sText, InStr(55, sText, sChrToCheck))
        Else
            sGreater55 = Mid(sText, InStrRev(sText, sChrToCheck, 55))
        End If
    End If

    ' If text is greater than 19 characters, lets build the string after 19 characters (depending on where the SPACE character is)
    If Len(sText) > 19 Then
        If InStr(19, sText, " ") > 0 Then
            sGreater19 = Mid(sText, InStr(19, sText, sChrToCheck))
        Else
            sGreater19 = Mid(sText, InStrRev(sText, sChrToCheck, 19))
        End If
        sGreater19 = Left(sGreater19, Len(sGreater19) - Len(sGreater55))
    End If

    ' Now lets build the complete string
    SetString = Left(sText, Len(sText) - (Len(sGreater19) + Len(sGreater55))) & vbLf & sGreater19 & vbLf & sGreater55

End Function
```

Comment: No worries, glad it helped. As per before, don't forget to accept one of the answers to close the query